"Я ему ничего не должен." vs "Я ничего ему не должен."
Does the nuance/emphasis vary between these two sentences?
Я ему ничего не должен. 

vs
Я ничего ему не должен.


Not in any perceptible way.
Depending on which word you would put the emphasis on while speaking, either of those options could yield a marginally better prosody (the natural flow of speech). But I can't imagine a situation where the choice of either of these two options would change the denotation (the face value of the phrase) in any significant way.

OK, thank you.  I saw it phrased the bottom way and according to ChatGPT it was a way to emphasize ему. Sounds like that was just a hallucination though.

Both sentences sound neutral unless you imply a logical stress. But just see the difference in the following phrases.
Ему я ничего не должен.
Ничего я ему не должен.
Я ему не должен ничего.
Я ничего не должен ему.
There's a difference.

Я ему ничего не должен emphasizes ему = "You don't owe HIM anything"
Я ничего ему не должен emphasizes ничего = "You don't owe him ANYTHING"
However, as it's mentioned earlier, these nuances are really tiny and the context of your conversation has more meaning than words order.

Did you mean "I don't owe HIM anything" and "I don't owe him ANYTHING"?

my foreigner-friend!) I'm from Russia by the way.)
No, between this two expressions there isn't any difference. You can also use "Я ни хрена ему не должен" / "Я ни черта ему не должен". But these two are more solid and expressive.
